# how change "for" for "while" in python, and try say the same

Tags: python

I have this code in Python that uses `for`. I need the same result using `while`, but I don't know how.

```
def arbolNavidad(n): 
    for a in range(1,n+1): 
        print (" " * (n-a) + "*" * (2 * a - 1))


altura = int(input("Altura del Arbol de Navidad: "))

arbolNavidad(altura)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `a` outside the loop, then increment it:

```
def arbolNavidad(n):
    a = 1
    while a <= n: 
        print (" " * (n-a) + "*" * (2 * a - 1))
        a += 1


altura = int(input("Altura del Arbol de Navidad: "))

arbolNavidad(altura)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
def arbolNavidad(n):
    j = 1
    # Or
    # j < n+1
    while j <= n:
        print (" " * (n-a) + "*" * (2 * a - 1))
        j+=1

altura = int(input("Altura del Arbol de Navidad: "))
arbolNavidad(altura)
```